# How to optimize a jpa query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, jpa

I have a query which is taking a bit more time to fetch data from mysql db. There is only few records in database

```
@Query("    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  Message n
    WHERE  n.deleted = false
      AND  n.sent = true
      AND  n.senderEnvelope.user = ?1
      AND  n.replyToMessage IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT m.replyToMessage
            FROM  Message m , Relationship r
            WHERE  m.deleted = false
              AND  m.sent = true
              AND  m.senderEnvelope.user = ?1
              AND  ?2 MEMBER OF r.categories 
                          )
       ")
Long countUniqueRepliesSentByUser(User currentUser ,
            RecommendationCategory recommendationCategory);
```

Is there is a way by which i can optimize this query or right it in another way.
Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you execute the corresponding SQL statement in database and check that performs well or not, and secondly check is connectivity to database is fine or not?

Comment: No it is also not performing well executing on database. Yes connectivity to database is fine.

Comment: can you post your entities (Message and Relationship)?

Comment: So if the SQL query (which you haven't posted) is performing "badly" then you follow normal rules on how to optimise your SQL query first, and then work back to JPQL once you've done that! Nothing JPA specific here

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that there is no relationship specified for these two tables:

```
FROM  Message m , Relationship r
```

That leads to a costly "cross join".

This seems like a syntax error; what was it supposed to mean??:

```
AND  ?2 MEMBER OF r.categories
```

After fixing those, then deal with `IN`.  `IN ( SELECT DISTINCT ... )` is poorly optimized.  Furthermore the `DISTINCT` is, as some level, redundant.  Consider changing it to

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ...
          AND n.replyToMessage = m.replyToMessage )
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any query you are asking about.